# Getting function arguments at runtime in Go

Tags: go, rtti

How to get function arguments in Go at runtime, all I know is only how to get function name:

```
pc, file, line, ok := runtime.Caller(2)
rt := runtime.FuncForPC(pc)
return rt.Name() // Foo
```

What I need is something like this:

```
Foo(1,2,3)
// Foo_1_2_3
```

Comment: I've passed hours reading docs and trying to find an answer to your question. But, hummm what i can say is i didn't found anything related to it. If you find any solution please update your question or answer it. It would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: can you post a runnable example?

Comment: @nexus66 XD so.. I haven't found any solution yet, what I did was write the name and argument manually for each function.. something like this:
`ram_key := "FunctionName" + I.ToS(arg1) + "_" + I.ToS(arg2) + "_" + I.ToS(arg3)` // not using any reflection at all so it probably faster

Comment: @Kokizzu: this can be done by pre-processing the source. See [godebug](https://github.com/mailgun/godebug/) or a simpler proof of concept [gotrace](https://github.com/jbardin/gotrace/). There's definitely no "safe" way to do it at runtime.

Answer (score 4):

Not a full answer, but maybe this can help :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(f1))
    for index := 0; index < reflect.TypeOf(f1).NumIn(); index++ {
        fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(f1).In(index))
    }
}

func f1(a int, b string) {}
```

prints :

`func(int, string)
 int
 string`